# Extracting Attributes from External URL Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to assign a date that is extracted from the first "performanceDate" attribute in a JSON string. I'm pulling the string from an external URL. However, I can't seem to get a value.

Here is the code I've constructed:
    `

```
function(){
  var externalURL = "http://198.211.117.172/api/performances/" + {{PerformanceID}};
  $.getJSON(externalURL, function(json) {
    alert(performances.performanceDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  });
}
```

Here's an [example of the externalURL](http://198.211.117.172/api/performances/486) variable where I'm getting my JSON string.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what error are you getting? I do not see where you declare an object for json string. It should be something like `objJSON.performances.performanceDate[0]`

Comment: `performances` is an array - you need to loop through it.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure where I need to add the array or object. I'm not a developer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using variable in which you have got your returned output from JSON.
In your case, you are getting your result in 'json' variable. If you just want first performanceDate from the entire result and if you know the position of the 'performanceDate' variable then you can directly use it.

According to your external url, you should alert

```
alert(json.data.performances[0].performanceDate);
```

If you want all performance dates then you can use foreach loop

```
 $.each( json.data.performances, function( key, val ) {
     alert(val.performanceDate);
 });
```